# Electron NodeJS server to server communication using POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, electron

I am working on an assignment for school, and I have decided to make a chat application using Electron and NodeJS. All of the GUI is programmed, except for the server-side of things. My plan was to have two servers, where each would act as its own client AND server, only communicating with each other to send messages.

How would I get each server to communicate using POST requests? Does anybody know any fully functioning npm modules that can be used for this?

Comment: If you are making a chat application you should look at socket.io which uses websockets for live communication.

Comment: "How would I get each server to communicate using POST requests?" — What's the problem? Making a POST request? Listening for a POST request? Both of those should be trivial to solve with five minutes + Google. Is the problem something else? Like discovery of the services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use in server A : `socket.io`
in server B: `socket.io-client`

Like this:

> server A

```
// Load requirements
var http = require('http'),
io = require('socket.io');

// Create server & socket
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res)
{
  // Send HTML headers and message
  res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('<h1>404</h1>');
});
server.listen(8080);
io = io.listen(server);

// Add a connect listener
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
  console.log('Client connected.');

  // Disconnect listener
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('Client disconnected.');
  });
});
```

> server B

```
// Connect to server
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {reconnect: true});

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect', function(socket) { 
  console.log('Connected!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `React js`, there's quite examples on github.

Take a look at this examples:

https://github.com/ncuillery/react-chat-project

https://github.com/keithyong/chat-room

It's nice to see someone using Electron, I've just finished my first project with it, and I'm amazed.

As @Arcath has stated, you must use `socket.io`, it talks between frontend and backend. Whenever someone sends a chat message, React.js handles that message, and emits a socket message which the server recieves. The server then adds the socket message into the database.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Neither of those links appears to address the problem posed by the question anyway. They seem to be entirely about browser-server communication and not server-server communication.

Comment: Re edit: "As @Arcath has stated, you must use socket.io, it talks between frontend and backend. " — The question is asking about communicating between backend peers, not about between the frontend and backend.

Comment: @Quentin socket.io is not just for frontend to backend, can be used to communicate between backend servers too. using `socket-io-client`

Comment: Then your answer should (a) talk about that instead of frontend to backend and (b) give a proper answer instead of just naming a technology.

Comment: Ok I'm going to redo my answer.

Comment: Thank you both, Jordi and Quentin for helping me. Quentin, keep up the great community service!